# Unable to send Arraylist to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, mule

I am trying to send an arraylist from mule to salesforce to save some data, but I am getting the following exception.

`Status 500 Exception while executing: &#10;[{DocumentName=&quot;sample.pdf&quot;, Blobdata=[B@12a23ba8}, {DocumentName=&quot;sample2.pdf&quot;, Blobdata=[B@7ec5db40}]&#10; ^&#10;Unexpected character 'D' at index 2 (line 1, position 3), expected '&quot;' (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException). Message payload is of type: ArrayList`

```
Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character 'D' at index 2 (line 1, position 3), expected '"'
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.fail(JsonTokenizer.scala:190)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.require(JsonTokenizer.scala:187)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.readString(JsonTokenizer.scala:74)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.readObjectMembers(JsonTokenizer.scala:143)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.com$mulesoft$weave$reader$json$JsonTokenizer$$readObject(JsonTokenizer.scala:137)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer$$anonfun$readValue$1.apply$mcV$sp(JsonTokenizer.scala:37)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.inner(JsonTokenizer.scala:59)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.readValue(JsonTokenizer.scala:37)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.values$1(JsonTokenizer.scala:157)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.com$mulesoft$weave$reader$json$JsonTokenizer$$readArray(JsonTokenizer.scala:160)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer$$anonfun$readValue$2.apply$mcV$sp(JsonTokenizer.scala:38)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.inner(JsonTokenizer.scala:59)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.readValue(JsonTokenizer.scala:38)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonTokenizer.tokens(JsonTokenizer.scala:16)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonReader.root(JsonReader.scala:17)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.reader.ReusableReader.root(ReusableReader.scala:12)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ExecutionContext$InternalExecutionContext$$anonfun$3.apply(ExecutionContext.scala:29)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ExecutionContext$InternalExecutionContext$$anonfun$3.apply(ExecutionContext.scala:26)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:116)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ExecutionContext$InternalExecutionContext.<init>(ExecutionContext.scala:26)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ExecutionContext$.apply(ExecutionContext.scala:126)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.execute(Engine.scala:216)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor.execute(WeaveMessageProcessor.scala:119)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor.process(WeaveMessageProcessor.scala:68)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.Blo...
```

Above is the exception I am getting while trying to send the list.
How do i fix it?

Comment: Can you post your code and the input data ? It seems a DataWeave exception and the question shows that the issue is at the SalesFroce

Answer (score 0):

If your Salesforce connector is place after your DataWeave transformer, DataSense should provide metadata info to the DataWeave transformer.

So the DataWeave transformer output metadata should show you what to provide to Salesforce. That should be a Salesforce specific object.

Some more info here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-tutorial

Example inserting contacts in Salesforce: https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/import-contacts-into-salesforce